# Integration General Technique (Polynomials)

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Let $P(x) = a_nx^n + ..... a_1x + a_0$

Is there a general technique for integrating

$$\frac{P(x)}{\sqrt{Ax^2 + Bx + C}}$$

Similarly is there a general method for

$$\frac{1}{P(x)\sqrt{Ax^2 + Bx + C}}$$

And finally is there a general method for

$$\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)\sqrt{Ax^2 + Bx + C}}$$

Where Q(x) is similarly defined to P(x).

Comment: Is this in relation to the top one?

Comment: It is sometimes useful to use a substitution involving $sinh$,$cosh$ $tanh$ etc

Comment: I just found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution in the comments of another MSE question. Consequently I retracted my previous overly complicated comments; this is a simpler way to proceed if you are in the general case. That said, trigonometric substitution does provide a way to motivate the Euler substitutions.

Comment: For example, when $A>0$ and $C-B^2/4A \geq 0$, $\sqrt{Ax^2+Bx+C}=\sqrt{A(x+B/2A)^2+C-B^2/4A}$ is the length of the hypotenuse of a right triangle whose legs have length $\sqrt{A}(x+B/2A)$ and $\sqrt{C-B^2/4A}$. Then if $\theta$ is opposite the first leg, $x=\frac{\sqrt{C-B^2/4A}}{\sqrt{A}} \tan(\theta) - B/2A$ and $\sqrt{Ax^2+Bx+C}=\sqrt{C-B^2/4A} \sec(\theta)$. The resulting trig integral suggests a substitution which is ultimately the same as the Euler substitution.